# No match when trying to compare two positions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a snake game. My problem is when the snake meets the food, there is no match. Please check the function `eat()` in my code, where `x` needs to be equal `food_position_x` and `y` needs to be equal `food_position_y`.

```js
(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      x = 0,
      y = 0,
      speed = 1;
      x_move = speed, 
      y_move = 0,
      food_position_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width); 
      food_position_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height); 

  function eat() {
    if (x == food_position_x && y == food_position_y) { 
      alert('Match!');      
    }
  }
  
  // Drawing
  function draw() {
    eat();
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {      
      draw();      
    });    
    // Draw the snake
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(Math.floor(x/10)*10, Math.floor(y/10)*10, 10, 10);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'; 
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

    // Draw the food
    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.rect(Math.floor(food_position_x/10)*10, Math.floor(food_position_y/10)*10, 10, 10);    
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

    // Increase the value of x and y in order to animate
    x = x + x_move;
    y = y + y_move;       
  } 
  draw();

  // Key Pressing
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
      case 40: // Moving down
        if (x_move != 0 && y_move != -1) {
          x_move = 0;
          y_move = speed;
        }
      break;
      case 39: // Moving right
        if (x_move != -1 && y_move != 0) {
          x_move = speed;
          y_move = 0; 
        }
      break;
      case 38: // Moving top
        if (x_move != 0 && y_move != 1) {
          x_move = 0;
          y_move = -speed; 
        }
      break;
      case 37: // Moving left
        if (x_move != 1 && y_move != 0) {
          x_move = -speed;
          y_move = 0; 
        }
      break;
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
canvas { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="300" id="canvas">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like `food_position_x` and `food_position_y` can be any integer coordinate on the canvas, but your snake position is always divisible by 10. You're drawing the food on the same 10-pixel grid as the snake, but it's actual position is somewhere between two cells. As a first step, force the food's position to be divisible by 10 when you set it up.

Comment: Same goes for your snake position, you're drawing it on a 10-pixel grid, but its actual position could be any integer. So it looks like you're on top of the food drawn at (80, 120) when in fact the snake is at (82, 129) and the food at (85, 124).

Answer (score 1):

The below code is a working solution.  The problem is that you're measuring by pixels, so the exact pixel coordinates won't always match.  If you expand it to a range (10 pixels, in this answer, but you can adjust that) you'll catch the match better.

I also added a flag (`matched`) so that you won't keep getting the "Match!" message for each pixel that the snake moves within the acceptable range.

You can adjust the range if you want, but that range works well on a standard desktop monitor.

```js
    (function() {
      var matched = false;
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
          ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
          x = 0,
          y = 0,
          speed = 1;
          x_move = speed, 
          y_move = 0,
          food_position_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width); 
          food_position_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height); 

      function eat() {
        var xdiff = food_position_x - x;
        var ydiff = food_position_y - y;
        if ((xdiff > -6 && xdiff < 6) && (ydiff > -6 && ydiff < 6) && !matched) { 
          alert('Match!');
          matched = true;
        }
        else if (!(xdiff > -5 && xdiff < 5) && (ydiff > -5 && ydiff < 5)) {
            matched = false;
        }
      }
      
      // Drawing
      function draw() {
        eat();
        requestAnimationFrame(function() {      
          draw();      
        });    
        // Draw the snake
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(Math.floor(x/10)*10, Math.floor(y/10)*10, 10, 10);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
        ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'; 
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();

        // Draw the food
        ctx.beginPath(); 
        ctx.rect(Math.floor(food_position_x/10)*10, Math.floor(food_position_y/10)*10, 10, 10);    
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();

        // Increase the value of x and y in order to animate
        x = x + x_move;
        y = y + y_move;       
      } 
      draw();

      // Key Pressing
      document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        switch(event.keyCode) {
          case 40: // Moving down
            if (x_move != 0 && y_move != -1) {
              x_move = 0;
              y_move = speed;
            }
          break;
          case 39: // Moving right
            if (x_move != -1 && y_move != 0) {
              x_move = speed;
              y_move = 0; 
            }
          break;
          case 38: // Moving top
            if (x_move != 0 && y_move != 1) {
              x_move = 0;
              y_move = -speed; 
            }
          break;
          case 37: // Moving left
            if (x_move != 1 && y_move != 0) {
              x_move = -speed;
              y_move = 0; 
            }
          break;
        }
      });
    })();
```

```css
    canvas { background-color: red; }
```

```html
    <canvas width="500" height="300" id="canvas">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tested your solution. For some reasons sometimes I do not get a match.

Comment: @RezaSaadati you may need to increase the range (instead of -5 to 5, maybe try -7 to 7).  That will probably vary depending on screen size/resolution.  Another idea would be to do what Eric Dobbs suggested and only use positions divisible by 10 for the food and the snake.